# Is it possible to represent a type similar to ArrayList<ArrayList <String>> as as OData Entity?

Tags: java, odata, olingo

I'm creating an OData REST Service to provide read-only access to some values in a database, the values are Strings, however there can be an arbitrary amount of Rows and Columns of them. Here is my current schema:

```xml
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx" Version="4.0">
<edmx:DataServices>
<Schema xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm" Namespace="olingo.server">
<EntityType Name="Form">
<Key>
<PropertyRef Name="FormId"/>
</Key>
<Property Name="FormId" Type="Edm.Int32"/>
<Property Name="Name" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="Description" Type="Edm.String"/>
<Property Name="UUID" Type="Edm.Guid"/>
<Property Name="Rows" Type="Collection(olingo.server.Cell)"/>
</EntityType>
<ComplexType Name="Cell">
<Property Name="Cell" Type="Collection(Edm.String)"/>
</ComplexType>
<EntityContainer Name="Container">
<EntitySet Name="Forms" EntityType="olingo.server.Form"/>
</EntityContainer>
</Schema>
</edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

This looks correct to me, Rows are defined as a Collection of Cell types, and Cell is defined as a Collection of Strings. So we have Collection(Collection(String)) if I'm understanding this correctly.

So now I'm trying to use some dummy data for testing, but no matter what I do, Rows comes back null, like so

```xml
<d:Rows m:null="true"/>
```

Here's the functions related to generating the dummy data

```java
private EntityCollection createForms() {
    EntityCollection entitySet = new EntityCollection();
    Entity el = new Entity()
        .addProperty(createPrimitive("FormId", 1))
        .addProperty(createPrimitive("Name", "New Test"))
        .addProperty(createPrimitive("Description", "Test"))
        .addProperty(createPrimitive("UUID", UUID.fromString("ef35f489-339a-4b41-a5d2-cb2426ed6a77")))
        .addProperty(createRow(Arrays.asList("1","1","1","Test 2","blue","rabbit","blah","06/12/2020")));
    el.setId(createId(JPEdmProvider.ES_FORMS_NAME, 1));
    entitySet.getEntities().add(el);

    el = new Entity()
        .addProperty(createPrimitive("FormId", 2))
        .addProperty(createPrimitive("Name", "Space Shuttle"))
        .addProperty(createPrimitive("Description", "Lego Space Shuttle"))
        .addProperty(createPrimitive("UUID", UUID.fromString("f44173d8-c319-482e-b078-03b18ce7827f")))
        .addProperty(createRow(Arrays.asList("1","1","1","Test 2","blue","rabbit","blah","06/12/2020")));
    el.setId(createId(JPEdmProvider.ES_FORMS_NAME, 2));
    entitySet.getEntities().add(el);

    for (Entity entity:entitySet.getEntities()) {
      entity.setType(JPEdmProvider.ET_FORM.getFullQualifiedNameAsString());
    }
    return entitySet;
  }

  private Property createRow(final List<String> data) {
    ComplexValue complexValue=new ComplexValue();
    List<Property> addressProperties = complexValue.getValue();
    
    data.forEach((str) -> {
        addressProperties.add(createPrimitive("Data", str));
      });
    return new Property(null, "Cell", ValueType.COMPLEX, complexValue);
  }

  private Property createPrimitive(final String name, final Object value) {
    return new Property(null, name, ValueType.PRIMITIVE, value);
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!